# How does Qt handle stack-allocated objects

Tags: c++, qt

I don't understand how Qt can delete all QObject's children without double deleting something if it was statically allocated.

Basically, if I do it the usual way, it looks like this :

```
QWidget Window(nullptr);
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(&Window);
Window.show();
return App.exec(); 
//When app ends, Window gets deleted 
//because it was statically allocated
//And then, Window deletes button because it's its child.
```

But I can also do this without crash :

```
QWidget Window(nullptr);
QPushButton button(&Window);
Window.show();
return App.exec(); 
//When app ends, button then Window get deleted 
//because they were statically allocated
//And then, Window (should) delete button AGAIN because it's its child, thus crashing 
//the program. But it doesn't. Why ?
```

Does Qt know how I created QPushButton, or did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes, you do miss something, namely, that undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @n.m.: Nothing undefined here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen maybe nothing undefined in this example, I'm only saying that absence of crash proves nothing.

Comment: @n.m.: Then you might want to say that instead of saying something irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a `QObject` is destroyed, it removes itself from its parent, if it has one. Therefore when the `Window` is destroyed, it doesn't try to destroy the `QPushButton`, because the button is no longer in the window's list of children.

Relevant documentation below. It also mentions the fact that if the declaration order of the objects doesn't match the parent/child relationship order, it might indeed cause an object to be destroyed twice. Which is a bad thing.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: Got it. It was esay to check that if I create the button before the window, then use button.setParent(&window), it indeed crashes.
It's so... elegant :D

Comment: @bisthebis "Elegant" is not the word I'd use... mixing RAII and `QObject`'s parenting system is just bad. Also note that the parent-child system works equally bad in conjunction with smart pointers, which is a pity as they are one of the keystones in modern C++.

Comment: @rubenvb : well, I must admit it's not good for consistency, but I'm quite happy not to have to put every child in a unique_ptr. On the other side, when I have a random, non-Qt object as a member of my window class, It's hard to choose between using a unique_ptr or making it child of window. What would you suggest for Qt to do ?